# how to load swf as2 in android?

Tags: android, flash, actionscript-2

I have some swf files in as2 format. I wrote a loader in as3 format that loads my as2 files. It is correct in windows but doesn't work in android. I know Adobe air android doesn't support as2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android AIR runtime does not include the AS2 virtual machine - so it doesn't know how to play AS2 content.

It is possible to get AS2  into an AIR for Android app, however this only works via the browser, and the browser needs to have a Flash player.

If you plan to keep using actionscript The best solution is to use AS3.